# xspdocument appears to be null when saving a new document

Tags: xpages

This is hard to explain so I appreciate your reading through this.

I have an xPages app with three tabs.  Each tab has it's own custom control.  ON the first custom control I have the following code:

```
<xp:this.data>
<xp:dominoDocument var="vendorApplication" formName="frmVendorApplication"
action="editDocument" computeWithForm="onsave">
<xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:( param.vendorAppNoteID || "");}]]>
</xp:this.documentId>
</xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

On the last tab I have the following code to save the document

```
vendorApplication.save();
var vendorAppDocument = vendorApplication.getDocument();
//  a bunch of code that does vendorAppDocument.ReplaceItemValues( ..... )
vendorAppDocument.save();
```

The problem I am having is when I try to save a NEW document I get all the way to the vendorAppDocument.save() then I get an error about it being null.  If I am editing an existing document it's fine.

I suspect this has to do with the vendorApplication ( XSPDocument ) not being set when it's a new document.  How can I set vendorApplication to the current XSPDocument?  Or do you see something else that is missing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why call `replaceItemValue` on the "back end" document instead of just writing all the items to `vendorApplication` prior to saving it?

Comment: I thought I had to use the back end to add values to fields that do not exist on the form.

Comment: Nope. The form specified in the `formName` attribute of the data source doesn't even need to exist. Linking to existing form design elements is mostly for convenience (allowing Designer to provide a list of fields to link components to, enforcement of data types, etc.). But you can bind components to fields not defined on a form, and data sources to forms that don't exist. `dataSource.setValue("arbitraryField", someValue)` will create the specified item, whether the field is defined, or whether there's even a form design element.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use getDocument(true) to have the backend document synced with changes made in the frontend document. So do the following:

```
vendorApplication.save();
var vendorAppDocument = vendorApplication.getDocument(true);
//  a bunch of code that does vendorAppDocument.ReplaceItemValues( ..... )
vendorAppDocument.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was as simple as removing the action="editDocument"

```
<xp:this.data>
<xp:dominoDocument var="vendorApplication" formName="frmVendorApplication"
action="editDocument" computeWithForm="onsave">
```